# PHP - Push Array Associative to Another Array associative

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array which the length both of array is same.
Let's say that first arrays have tree elements,
and the second array also three elements too.
This is the first array.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [container] => SITU9026744
        [seal] => SITC853014
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [container] => SITU9026744
        [seal] => SITC853014
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [container] => SITU9026744
        [seal] => SITC853014
    )
)
```

The second array is  :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [size] => 40x80x1.15x6M
        [weight] => 12800
        [piece_per_bundle] => 50
        [total_bundle] => 20
        [total_piece] => 1000
        [total_quantity_(MTs)] => 12800
        [tanggal_plan_masuk] => 01-05-2017
        [nama_file] => PACKING LIST 68 LOT 1 WITH COLORS MARK.xlsx
        [urut] => 1
        [row] => 34
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [size] => 40x60x1.15x6M
        [weight] => 10630
        [piece_per_bundle] => 50
        [total_bundle] => 10
        [total_piece] => 500
        [total_quantity_(MTs)] => 5315
        [tanggal_plan_masuk] => 01-05-2017
        [nama_file] => PACKING LIST 68 LOT 1 WITH COLORS MARK.xlsx
        [urut] => 2
        [row] => 35
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [size] => 19x19x0.92x6M
        [weight] => 3160
        [piece_per_bundle] => 100
        [total_bundle] => 12
        [total_piece] => 1200
        [total_quantity_(MTs)] => 3792
        [tanggal_plan_masuk] => 01-05-2017
        [nama_file] => PACKING LIST 68 LOT 1 WITH COLORS MARK.xlsx
        [urut] => 3
        [row] => 36
    )
)
```

Then, I need like this :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [size] => 40x80x1.15x6M
        [weight] => 12800
        [piece_per_bundle] => 50
        [total_bundle] => 20
        [total_piece] => 1000
        [total_quantity_(MTs)] => 12800
        [tanggal_plan_masuk] => 01-05-2017
        [nama_file] => PACKING LIST 68 LOT 1 WITH COLORS MARK.xlsx
        [urut] => 1
        [row] => 34
        [container] => SITU9026744
        [seal] => SITC853014
    )

[1] => Array 
    (
        [size] => 40x60x1.15x6M
        [weight] => 10630
        [piece_per_bundle] => 50
        [total_bundle] => 10
        [total_piece] => 500
        [total_quantity_(MTs)] => 5315
        [tanggal_plan_masuk] => 01-05-2017
        [nama_file] => PACKING LIST 68 LOT 1 WITH COLORS MARK.xlsx
        [urut] => 2
        [row] => 35
        [container] => SITU9026744
        [seal] => SITC853014
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [size] => 19x19x0.92x6M
        [weight] => 3160
        [piece_per_bundle] => 100
        [total_bundle] => 12
        [total_piece] => 1200
        [total_quantity_(MTs)] => 3792
        [tanggal_plan_masuk] => 01-05-2017
        [nama_file] => PACKING LIST 68 LOT 1 WITH COLORS MARK.xlsx
        [urut] => 3
        [row] => 36
        [container] => SITU9026744
        [seal] => SITC853014
    )
)
```

What key that we can use to push the first key => value array into second key => value.

Please advise.

Comment: Tried  array_combine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably want the [`array_replace_recursive`](http://php.net/array_replace_recursive) function:

```
<?php
$ar1 = [
    [
        'a' => 1,
        'b' => 2
    ],
    [
        'a' => 3,
        'b' => 4
    ]
];
$ar2 = [
    [
        'c' => 15
    ],
    [
        'c' => 16
    ]
];

$res = array_replace_recursive($ar1, $ar2);
var_dump($res);
```

output will be:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["a"]=>
    int(1)
    ["b"]=>
    int(2)
    ["c"]=>
    int(15)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["a"]=>
    int(3)
    ["b"]=>
    int(4)
    ["c"]=>
    int(16)
  }
}
```

Here is a working example:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fec68f6c555aa8bd1dcbc471ef95172cf5a1e9be